# Save bitlocker recovery key to an Active Directory user-account in Azure

Tags: windows-10, active-directory, bitlocker

I have set up a new laptop for a colleague. I have first created a local admin account for system administration and installing software. However, the colleague will use the laptop using his/her local Active Directory user account which is set up as standard user.

Since I enabled BitLocker using the local admin account, there is no option for the user account to save the recovery key to the Cloud, i.e. to Azure. I have saved the recovery key in a file on a network drive and I have also printed it on paper.

Is there a way to associate the recovery key to the domain-user account in Azure?
I found no option to upload a recovery key in our Azure portal.

---

If I make the User, i.e., the domain-user account, an administrator on his/her machine, then I can save the recovery key in the Cloud.

However, I do not want the domain-user to be an administrator on his/her machine. The users should use a local administrator account.

Comment: "Is there a way to associate the recovery key to the user account in Azure?" - I am confused, are you or are you not using Azure, you made it clear that you are NOT using an Azure Active Directory domain?

Comment: I guess we are using Azure, since we do have an Azure portal.

Comment: You should clarify your question in that case.  Are you an Administrator on the AD domain?  If you are not, then as an end user, if it's not already configured to allow you to (specifically force you) to backup your BItLocker key that is likely the reason the option to backup your BitLocker recovery key is missing.